# Sidebar with absolute position mess my content area

Tags: html, css, fixed

im trying to create a responsive layout of a webpage that haves a sidebar on de left (with a black background that MUST cover all the height of the window) and a content column to fill with php content. Im having trouble beacuse the content area is display under the sidebar content.
this is my code so far
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "contenedor">
        <!-- NAVEGADOR -->
        <div class = "grilla">
            <nav class = "col col-nav">
                <img src="" alt = "logo">
                <h3>frisson.</h3>
                <ul class = "links">
                    <li>Posts</li>
                    <li>Noticias</li>
                    <li>Eventos</li>
                    <li>Contacto</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class = "redes">
                    <li>facebook</li>
                    <li>instagram</li>
                    <li>twitter</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- CONTENIDO -->
            <div class = "col col-content">
                <section class = "carta">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <footer>
            <h1></h1>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

and this is my css:

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body{
    height:100%;
}

.contenedor{
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.grilla{
    width:100%;
}

.col{
    background-color: #310138;
    float:left;
}

.col-nav{
    width:20%;
    color:white;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}

.col-content{
    width: 80%;
}

@media (max-width: 780px){
    .col{
        width:100% !important;
    }

}
```

Comment: the only solution i found is adding margin-left: (sidebar width). but i dont think thats clean

Comment: please add margin-left: auto; or  float: right; to .col-content styles.. i hope it will solve your problem..